# JAva netty отправка сообщений клиенту

Tags: java, netty

Не получаю ответа от сервера исключений ни каких. Не знаю уже что делать, помогите люди добрые!
1 хендлер

```
public class KeysKeeperHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter  {

    private Cache cache;

    public KeysKeeperHandler(Cache cache) {
        this.cache = cache;
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {

        Packet packet = (Packet)msg;
        Responce responce = new Responce();
        if (!packet.getKey().isEmpty() && packet.getValue() != null){
            try {
                this.cache.addItem(packet.getKey(),packet.getValue());
                responce.setStatusCode(200);
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (OutOfMemoryError e){
                this.cache.saveRelease();

            }
        }

        if(!packet.getKey().isEmpty() && packet.getValue() == null){
            responce.setBody(this.cache.getItem(packet.getKey()));
        }

        final ChannelFuture f = ctx.write(responce);
        f.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
                assert f == future;
                ctx.close();
            }
        });
    }

    public static byte[] objectToByteArray(Object obj) throws Exception
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        try
        {
            oos.writeObject(obj);
            return baos.toByteArray();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            oos.close();
            baos.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

2 хендлер

```
public class TrafficEncoder extends MessageToByteEncoder<Responce>{

    @Override
    protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Responce msg, ByteBuf out) throws Exception {
        out.writeBytes(objectToByteArray(msg));
    }

    public static byte[] objectToByteArray(Object obj) throws Exception {
        try(ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
            oos.writeObject(obj);
            return baos.toByteArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Не помню в Netty API классов `Packet` и `Response`. Откуда они?

Comment: это мои структуры данных  Packet я получаю от клиента Response возвращаю
Есть еще один  хендлер это MessageToByteDencoder c помощью которого я получаю Packet в основном хендлере

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Попробовал ваш пример,  все равно не получаю ответа от сервера. C клиента на сервер все отправляться а от сервера ничего